# Byte order for 4 channel Bitmap to feed into Tensorflow frozen model

Tags: java, android, python, opencv, tensorflow

I'm trying to get an Android Bitmap into the same format I fed into my Tensorflow model in python.

Here's how it is done originally in the TensorFlowObjectDetectionAPIModel:

```
 bitmap.getPixels(intValues, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());


    for (int i = 0; i < intValues.length; ++i) {
      byteValues[i * 3 + 2] = (byte) (intValues[i] & 0xFF);
      byteValues[i * 3 + 1] = (byte) ((intValues[i] >> 8) & 0xFF);
      byteValues[i * 3] = (byte) ((intValues[i] >> 16) & 0xFF);
    }
```

There are a few issues with doing this for a 4 channel (RGBD) Bitmap. From what I understand, `Bitmap.setPreMultiplied` has to be set to false in order for the Bitmap to not treat the 4th channel as Alpha info, multiplying it to the other three channels.

This is what I thought the solution would be intuitively (assuming `Bitmap.setPreMultiplied(false)`:

```
    bitmap.getPixels(intValues, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

//grabbing the 4 channels into 4 consecutive values of  byteValues
for (int i = 0; i < intValues.length; ++i) {
    byteValues[i * 4 + 2] = (byte) (intValues[i] & 0xFF);
    byteValues[i * 4 + 1] = (byte) ((intValues[i] >> 8) & 0xFF);
    byteValues[i * 4] = (byte) ((intValues[i] >> 16) & 0xFF);
    byteValues[i * 4 + 3] = (byte) ((intValues[i] >> 24) & 0xFF);
}
```

However, loading the exact same RGB and Depth Image I use in python, I get different (bad) recognition results. But in order to create the tf.record file, I had to modify the way the image was saved, pulling from two files as shown here:

```
image = cv2.imread(full_path)[:, :, ::-1]
print(image.tostring())
background = cv2.imread(full_path.replace('JPEG', 'Depth').replace('R', 
'D').replace('jpg', 'png'), 0)
background = np.reshape(background, (480,320,1))
# Image and background are numpy arrays that has dimension of H x W x 3 and H x W x 1
# Concatenate them on depth channel to create an H x W x 4 input
inputs_stacked = np.concatenate([image, background], axis=-1)
# Encode your input as string
encoded_inputs = inputs_stacked.tostring()
```

Then, later is saved under `tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={` as `'image/encoded': dataset_util.bytes_feature(encoded_inputs)`

What I need to know, ultimately, is how I can get the byte stream in Android Java to match whatever it is in tensorflow, which is a H x W x 4 numpy array that gets fed to the object detection api's dataset_util.

Answer (score 0):

according to Tensorflow official documents if you have a input shape with dimensions like `[1 224 224 3]` and lets say you have an image in your `drawable` directory called `image23` then to get your desired input you have to follow this steps :

```
   Bitmap bitmap = 
   Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), 
   R.drawable.image23), 224, 224, true);
   
 ByteBuffer input = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(224 * 224 * 3 *4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
for (int y = 0; y < 224; y++) {
  for (int x = 0; x < 224; x++) {
    int px = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);

    // Get channel values from the pixel value.
    int r = Color.red(px);
    int g = Color.green(px);
    int b = Color.blue(px);

    // Normalize channel values to [-1.0, 1.0]. This requirement depends
    // on the model. For example, some models might require values to be
    // normalized to the range [0.0, 1.0] instead.
    float rf = (r - 127) / 255.0f;
    float gf = (g - 127) / 255.0f;
    float bf = (b - 127) / 255.0f;

    input.putFloat(rf);
    input.putFloat(gf);
    input.putFloat(bf);
}
 }
```

the `input` now is ready to be fed to `Tensorflow.run(input, output)` function.